# How can I check the HTTP calls my unit test makes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2015. This link makes it look easy:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/05/04/introducing-visual-studios-network-tool/

However, that menu option does not exist. Instead, it is under the Analyze > Performance Profiler menu. However, the network profiling tools are not selectable:

[image]

I have set the startup project to be my unit test project, but no luck.

My question: when running a unit test, how can I check what network calls are made?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler is a good alternative if no one is able to help you get VS2015 working. Also works for all HTTP traffic from your box and can decrypt HTTPS

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler